# Passing stream to job as parameter

Tags: spring-batch

Is there a way to pass a stream while launching the job through job Launcher, something similar to passing jobParameters?

I have a separate service for getting file and then I want to initiate the batch job to load it.

Code scenario :

Consider this [sample](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-samples/tree/master/batch-boot-simple). Here job is defined but actual launcher resides in the dependency [underneath](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-batch-web).

So consider in [sample](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-samples/tree/master/batch-boot-simple), I add a controller which read user's input file and then trigger the sample-job defined in [sample](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-samples/tree/master/batch-boot-simple) which is run by joblauncher.run of [underneath](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-starter-batch-web).

I was thinking to pass this file stream directly to the job's reader instead of writing it to external disc and reading in Reader's setSeResource

Comment: Found the following with some suggestions :
https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-966

Comment: Can you add the code with which you launch the job? I think you could simply use a static Map somewhere in your code to share objects between your service and your job.

Comment: @Thrax : I have edited the initial question with Code Scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the sample code you provided, I think you could do something like this :

1) Declare a static HashMap in the `SimpleJobConfiguration` class.

```
public static Map<String, Object> customStorage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

2) Populate this map from your service

```
SimpleJobConfiguration.customStorage.put("key", yourStream);
```

3) Use this static map in the `setResource` method of your `ItemReader` (as said in your previous question)

```
@Override
public void setResource(Resource resource) {

    // Get your stream from the static map
    Byte[] stream = (Byte[]) SimpleJobConfiguration.customStorage.get("key");

    // Convert byte array to input stream
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream);

    // Create springbatch input stream resource
    InputStreamResource res = new InputStreamResource(is);

    // Set resource
    super.setResource(res);
}
```

This solution will only work if your service is next to your jobLauncher.